# Term to describe the space left between blocks of code (e.g. in a script)?

Tags: terminology

What's the correct term for the space between blocks of code? The best I have come up with is 'block delimiter' (as in code block delimiter)

#### Background

I'm writing some documentation and need to know what the space between blocks of code is called. I can see a very common pattern is to leave a single line gap (in other words, `\n\n` goes between the last character of the last code block and the first character of the next code block - examples [here](https://ourcodingclub.github.io/2017/04/25/etiquette.html)).

#### Question

What is the appropriate term for the space between the last character of a code block and the first character of the following code block?

Answer (score 1):

Consider term **padding line between blocks** as inspired by ESLint's rule [padding lines between statements](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements):

> Require or disallow padding lines between statements
>   (padding-line-between-statements)
>
> This rule requires or disallows blank lines between the given 2 kinds
>   of statements. Properly blank lines help developers to understand the
>   code.

Comment: Great suggestion. I will use 'padding' (unless I can find a more general term that encompasses things like multiple lines, and elaborate delineators, like groups of symbols coders may have copied or created - e.g 1 or more rows of `#####`) .